# Java Hibernate, a way to track native exceptions

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, try-catch

```
String nativeSql = "Some random non-sql stuff";
Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
List <?> result = sess.createSQLQuery(nativeSql).list();
```

In case, if nativeSql request isn't a valid one, how do I catch a native exception (ex: PSQLException)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate will wrap any SQLExceptions into a `org.hibernate.JDBCException`. So you want to catch this Exception type. If you explicitly need to access an actual PSQLException, you can retrieve it through the `getSQLException()` Method:

```
try {
    String nativeSql = "Some random non-sql stuff";
    Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
    List <?> result = sess.createSQLQuery(nativeSql).list();
} catch (JDBCException e) {
    SQLException sqlException = e.getSQLException;
    if (sqlException instanceof PSQLException) {
        PSQLException psqlException = (PSQLException) sqlException;
        // ... work with psqlException ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the docs for the [`Query.list()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#list%28%29) method you'll see that it throws `HibernateException`. If you check the docs for [`HibernateException`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/HibernateException.html) you'll see that `all SQLExceptions will be wrapped in some form of JDBCException.` `JDBCException` is a subclass of `HibernateException` (that's from the docs too). So you can either catch `HibernateException`, or `JDBCException` if you want to be more specific.

If you then look at the docs for [`JDBCException`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/JDBCException.html) you'll find a method called [`getSQLException`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/JDBCException.html#getSQLException%28%29) which returns `the underlying SQLException`. If you look at the docs for [`PSQLException`](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/util/PSQLException.html) you'll see that it extends `SQLException`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK , we cannot catch SQL native exception.

You might want to catch [JDBCException](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/JDBCException.html)  which

> Wraps an SQLException. Indicates that an exception occurred during a JDBC call.